# How to register a dynamically added custom component as a form control within a formgroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I have created some custom components, each of which implements [`ControlValueAccessor`](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html), in order that they may function as controls within a `FormGroup`. Usually, the only thing left to do would be to add the `formControlName` directive to each custom component in HTML.

However, I'm appending these components to the form at runtime using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39773331/1087131) technique.

My problem is that I cannot register these components with a containing `FormGroup` because I cannot declare the `formControlName` directive (or any directive, for that matter) with a dynamically added control.

**Has anyone else discovered how this might be possible?** At the moment, I'm wrapping each control inside another component so that I can use the `formControlName` directive but this is just too ugly and labor intensive.

---

**Below is a stripped down example of what I've already implemented  as a standalone Angular2 app**, which shows a component (`CustomComponent`) being programatically added on startup. In order to bind `CustomComponent` to the `FormGroup`, I've had to create `CustomContainerComponent` which I'd prefer to avoid.

```
import {
  Component, ReflectiveInjector, ViewContainerRef, Compiler, NgModule, ModuleWithComponentFactories,
  OnInit, ViewChild, forwardRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup, FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


export class AbstractValueAccessor<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  _value: T;
  get value(): T {
    return this._value;
  };

  set value(v: T) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: T) {
    this._value = value;
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}

export function MakeProvider(type: any) {
  return {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
    multi: true
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  template: `<input type="text" [value]="value">`,
  providers: [MakeProvider(CustomComponent)]
})
class CustomComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor<string> {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-container',
  template: `<div [formGroup]="formGroup"><app-custom formControlName="comp"></app-custom></div>`
})
class CustomContainerComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [CustomComponent, CustomContainerComponent]
})
class DynamicModule {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h4>Dynamic Components</h4><br>
             <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
               <div #dynamicContentPlaceholder></div>
             </form>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('dynamicContentPlaceholder', {read: ViewContainerRef})
  public readonly vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

  factory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<DynamicModule>;
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicModule)
      .then((moduleWithComponentFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<DynamicModule>) => {
        this.factory = moduleWithComponentFactories;
        const compFactory = this.factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.selector === 'app-custom-container');
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        let cmp = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, this.vcRef.length, injector, []);
        (<CustomContainerComponent>cmp.instance).formGroup = this.formGroup;
      });

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'comp': ['hello world']
    })
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: no code no cry... Add what you tried here

Comment: You're quite correct. I will add some code

Comment: thanks for update. What is the end use of your dynamically created components? Do you want to have a dynamic form with dynamic controls only or you want to have an ability to use the controls one-by-one?

Comment: The end use is to create a series of form controls based on a JSON schema obtained from the server. The schema will have references to each components selector (I just made a small update to onInit() method of AppComponent). My form only contains dynamic controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand your needs...

Weird thing is that you attach your form group inside of the `AppComponent`. Instead you could create the full form dynamically. In order to do that you need to implement two functions:

1. One that generates the template from JSON config
2. Another one that generates the form from JSON config

Then simply build a big form container component that contains all your inputs. I would recommend using a service here:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModuleFactory {

  public createComponent(jsonConfig: SomeInterface) {
    @Component({
      template: `
        <div ngForm="form">${ /* and here generate the template containing all inputs */ }</div>
      `
    })
    class FormContainerComponent {
      public form: FormGroup = /* generate a form here */;
    };

    return FormContainerComponent;
  }

  public createModule(component: any) {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ component ]
    })
    class MyModule {};

    return MyModule;
  }

}
```

This is of course just a simplified version, but it works fine for my project not only for the plain form but for nested form groups / arrays / controls.

Once you inject the service you can use these two functions to generate the module and the component.

Comment: This actually works very well. Thanks so much for your time.